# Service and IntentService, Which is better to run a service that poll database value from the server?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, intentservice, timertask

I had read quite a number of resources regarding the `Service` and `IntentService`. However when come to make a decision, I am not confident enough to choose which type to use in order to create a background service that will poll data from database in a time interval and stop it when I get the data I want since the data represent a status of a request, eg. ordering medicine confirmation status(pending, completed, in progress). I need to detect when a status is set to "completed" and send a notification to alert the user that the order is completed. After that the service will stop itself automatically. 
Please kindly advice. Thank you.

Comment: I would lean more towards `IntentService` just because it stops automatically once it runs out of work. But I haven't actually used it yet, so I can't be the most reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

Intent Service -

- Works in Worker Thread , not in Main Thread.
- Intended to execute their action is separate thread and then get shut down.
- They do perform their operation and stops.
- Ideal to perfrom things like htp get ,don't require to stay connected with server.

Service -

- Runs in main thread.
- Ideal when there is requirement to stay connected with server
  (i.e. permanent tcp connection), the way you can go is to have a service (not an intent one) that performs the networking stuff using an asynctask or a more classic thread hosted in the service

Comment: This is wrong. `IntentService` is a `Service`, it extends the `Service` class. A `Service` does not run on any thread, it is an object. The **methods of a class can run on any Thread**. The lifecycle methods (`onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, etc.) of `Service` and `IntentService` run on the main (UI) thread because they are called from the Android framework on the main (UI) thread. You can implement your own methods that run on any `Thread`, and also start your own threads to do whatever you want. `IntentService` is an extension of `Service` that provides a pool of managed threads...

Comment: ...and a mechanism for queueing and dequeueing work for these threads and also manages stopping itself when the queue of work is done. You can also use a `Service` and implement this processing yourself. It isn't rocket science. If you want more control over the management of the background threads, then you should not use `IntentService` because you don't know what it is doing.

Comment: The `onHandleIntent()` method of `IntentService` is called on a worker thread, not on the main (UI) thread. This is normally where you would put your "long-running operation".

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference. Use whatever you find easier. This question isn't worth spending any time worrying about. Just make sure you understand what code needs to run on the main (UI) thread and what code needs to run on a background (worker) thread. In `IntentService` the "long-running operation" needs to run in `onHandleIntent()` If you are using `Service` in `onStartCommand()` you would start your own background thread and execute the "long-running operation" on that.