# create a service to check external database frequently

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new in android and i develop an application that receive data from MYSQL external database using PHP.

I need to create a service to check frequently the database if there is any change made on it  the end user will get notification , so how i can create this like this service ?? 
any article to read ?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what are the specifics of the service? What are your requirements? Do you just want to poll your database, and then stop the service once data is retrieved. Will you need a separate worker thread to do this work?

You might want to look into [Intent Service](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/) for this. Documentation on it can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

A standard service may be fine too, but I'm not sure what the specifics are for your project, so I would read up them both and figure out exactly which would be best for your needs.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450804/service-and-intentservice-which-is-better-to-run-a-service-that-poll-database-v) SO question that gives a brief outline of them both.

Comment: firstly thanks for your reply .
but i need a service to work every time to check if another user insert data in the database all user notify with this and can access the new data inserted something like whatsapp idea

Comment: Ahh, then you might want to go with a Service in that case. Poll your server at whatever intervals you choose and do what you like with the results. You'll have to implement a BroadcastReceiver that will notify the Acitivty whenever the Service returns some now data. But that's just a very high level view. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: but do you have any article to begin with it , because i didn't know from where i must start

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, welcome to android development.
Unfortunately your seemingly simple example will require you to learn a lot of android concepts so I cannot answer your question as directly as you might like.

That said, the following site is very good for android tutorials
http://www.vogella.com/android.html

I have also compiled a list of android resources on my site that you might benefit from:
http://www.sage42.org/we-recommend/